# How to Bundle with Gulp + Rollup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, rollupjs

How may I configure gulp with rollup to bundle multiple transpiled javascript files into a single file? Essentially, I'd like to supply the (gulp) transpiled code to rollup to bundle. Would it be possible to choose the bundle mechanism, i.e. iife, namespacing, etc? Below is my gulpfile:

```
const {dest, series} = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

const transpile = () => {
 return tsProject
.src()
.pipe(tsProject())
.pipe(dest('dist'));
};

exports.default = transpile;
```